# PostgresSQL Function: Type of function parameter for in clause in select query?

Tags: database, postgresql, function

I have a postgres function defined below.

```
create or replace function example(anArray int[])
returns setof example
as $$
select *
from example where example.ex in (anArray);
    $$
language plpgsql;
```

My question is, what type does the anArray parameter need to be in order to properly evaluate the in clause, and how would you call it?

```
select * from example(123,123)
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're using an array you can use `WHERE example.ex = ANY(anArray)`. I believe `IN` looks at a set. You can manually type a list or use a sub-SELECT with `IN`. Postgres's `IN` documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN

Comment: You'd call your example like: `SELECT * FROM example(ARRAY[123, 123]);`

Comment: Thank you, both answers answered my question.